# join en django rest framework

Tags: django, rest, framework

tengo los siguientes modelos en django rest framework:

```
class Products(models.Model):
  name_product = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rel_category')
  category_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Product'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Products'


class Categories(models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 created_at = models.DateField('creation date', auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
 name_category = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

 class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

 def __str__(self):
    return self.name_category

 def __str__(self):
    return self.name_product



class Stores(models.Model):
   id_store = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   created_at = models.DateField('creation date', auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
   name_store = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
   telephone = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=False, null=False)
   number_identifier = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
   manager = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
   state_store = models.BooleanField('Estate', default=True)
   city = models.ForeignKey(Cities, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   logo_store = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
   description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)

   class Meta:
     verbose_name = 'Store'
     verbose_name_plural = 'Stores'

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name_store
```

En Sql para unir estos modelos seria de la siguiente manera:

```
select * from api_products pr 
join api_stores st on st.id_store = pr.store_id 
join api_categories cat on cat.id = pr.category_id;
```

Pero no consigo unirlos desde django con select_related no funciona por que los ForeignKey estan en el modelo contrario, el problema es que estoy trabajando con django rest entonces los serializers ponen problema
agradeceria la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En django rest framework manejas las relaciones con [Serializer relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Por ejemplo: si quisieras crear el serializador para saber que productos tiene una categoría seria así:

```
class Categories Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    rel_category = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Categories
        fields = [ 'rel_category', 'id', 'name_category',]
```

dónde rel_category es el related_name de la ForeignKey de categoría que llega a productos y ProductSerializer es el serializador de productos con los campos que quieres traer.